# github repo issue involving two account

Tags: git, github

My friend and I share the same user account on an ubuntu which is mainly used by my friend. I created a local repo on the ubuntu and created a remote repo on github using my own github account. 
After I pushed the local repo to the remote repo, I found something strange as shown in the picture below. The upper right circle shows my github account, and the other shows my friend's github account. How can I make these two the same??[image]

Comment: Most likely: You opened the repository on GitHub with your account, but `git push`ed with his SSH key.

Comment: I have set my own SSH key in my github account.

Comment: Yes, but you *pushed* using his key, not yours.

Comment: Can you run `git config -l` and see if the user.name attribute is set to your friend's name?

Comment: `git config -l` shows two user names. One is my friends', which is set globally. The other is mine, which I set locally, trying to fix that issue but failed. 
`user.email=dragonma1996@qq.com
user.name=maxiaolong
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=git@daniel.github.com:chanmankong/AL.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
user.name=daniel
user.email=vkccchan@gmail.com
`

Comment: I also set up a `~/.ssh/config`, so that we can use our own ssh keys respectively.